# Linux: Error output in code

Tags: linux, temp

I've got the code below, unfortunately it gives the following result. Something I do not understand. Does anyone know what I do wrong? The code is made for transferring data from to Domoticz (an open source Domotica system running on Linux).

```
cat: $: No such file or directory
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 91
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: SID=none; path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Domoticz server
SERVER="192.168.0.xxx:8080"

# DHT IDX
# le numéro de l IDX dans la liste des peripheriques
DHTIDX="25"
#DHTPIN
# LE GPIO ou est connecte le DHT11
DHTPIN="27"

# si vous avez un DHT22 modifiez plus bas sur la ligne Adafruit_DHT 11 par Adafruit_DHT 22
# TMPFILE : chemin pour fichier temporaire a placer dans le RAMDRIVE pour eviter les
# ecritures sur la SD card
# sinon chemin ou sera ecrit le fichier contenant les temperature
# /tmp/temper.txt est un bon choix si pas de RAMDRIVE installe
# consultez www.easydomoticz.com pour tout savoir

TMPFILE="/var/tmp/temper.txt"
# modif de patrick du 08/03/15 pour interroger que 5 fois maxi
cpt=0
while [ $cpt -lt 6 ]
do
TEMP=""
sleep 5
sudo nice -20 ./Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py 22 $DHTPIN > $TMPFILE
TEMP=$(cat $TMPFILE|grep Temp |awk '{print $3}')
if [ $TEMP ]
then
TEMP=$(cat $TMPFILE|grep Temp |awk '{print $3}')
HUM=$(cat $ $TMPFILE |grep Temp |awk '{print $7}')
#echo $TEMP
#echo $HUM
# Send data
curl -s -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://$SERVER/json.htm?type=command&amp;param=udevice&amp;idx=$DHTIDX&amp;nvalue=0&amp;svalue=$TEMP;$HUM;2"
TEMP=""
HUM=""
rm $TMPFILE
exit 0
fi
#echo $cpt
cpt=$(($cpt+1))
done
exit 1
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does this file exist? `/var/tmp/temper.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra `$` in this line

```
HUM=$(cat $ $TMPFILE |grep Temp |awk '{print $7}')
```

Try changing it to

```
HUM=$(cat $TMPFILE |grep Temp |awk '{print $7}')
```

and see if it works.